# Show text in tablecell one letter at a time

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, dispatch

I want to show each letter in my textLabel one letter at a time but putting a timer in the delegate is crashing the app. This is my current code without the timer

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:  NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CaptionCell")
cell.textLabel!.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
cell.backgroundColor =  preference.defaultBackgroundColor
cell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
cell.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleTopMargin]

cell.textLabel!.textColor = preference.defaultTextColor

if self.captionsArray.count > 2 {
    if (preference.inCall && (indexPath.row < self.captionsArray.count - 2)) {
        cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    }
}

let cap = self.captionsArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! CaptionObject
  cell.textLabel!.text = cap.caption
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

if cap.type == "11" {
    cell.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name:"Avenir-Black", size: CGFloat(preference.conversationTextSize))
} else {
    cell.textLabel!.font =  UIFont(name:"Avenir", size: CGFloat(preference.conversationTextSize))
}


return cell
```

}

Comment: Where it is crashing?

Comment: I had cell.textLabel!.text = cap.caption wrapped in dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { and that crashed it